# IOS Plist whitelist errors when *.url.com or * is added to Plist

Tags: ios, cordova, plist

I have two apps for Ios that are having the same errors when ran on a device.

ERROR whitelist rejection:

All the urls that are being white listed are in the plist externalHost array.

Even if I add * for a wild card to the plist I get the same error for all urls when when posting a form or calling google maps.

I have other apps that are doing just fine.'

Has anyone else had this issue and was able to resolve it?

Comment: Take a look at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795628/error-whitelist-rejection-in-phonegap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this out after searching the web for quite a while, the problem is that (if you are anything like me) you are adding the * incorrectly in Xcode to the Cordova.plist file.

You need to add the string as a child node of ExternalHosts.  To do this, first click on the little arrow to the left of the ExternalHosts label so that the arrow points downwards (this is crucial).  Then right-click on the ExternalHosts label and click on "Add Row".  Then set the new row value to whatever you want.

If you were doing it incorrectly like I was before, you might have been just hitting the + sign next to Externalhosts to add the value or adding the row while the little arrow was still pointing to the right (closed position).  This adds a new node but not a child node.