# Error: Whitelist rejection in Phonegap

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, whitelist

I'm new to mobile development. I'm using Phonegap/Cordova to create a cross-platform app. My code works well on Android but when I'm porting it to iPhone it's showing an error:

```
[143:2003] ERROR whitelist rejection: url="abc"
```

Now can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Use cordova's white-list pugin. Worked for me on both android and IOS platforms without any other mentioned changes. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> **Notice**: This answer only applies for PhoneGap version 1.x and below. From version 2.x onwards, whitelist configuration is done via `cordova.xml`.

You have to add allowed URLs into PhoneGap.plist's (or Cordova.plist) ExternalHosts array.

For example, if you want to allow access to this URL `http://www.myhost.com/path/file`, then add `www.myhost.com` as a new entry to `ExternalHosts` array.

If you want to allow access to content on all the subdomain of Google (e.g. `maps.google.com`, `mails.google.com`), you can add `*.google.com` as a new entry to `ExternalHosts` array.

I am not sure why you get "abc" in the link, though. Do you have "abc" as a link to anything? Is it URI fragment?

Comment: Any key name in the plist is fine ? or is it any particular key name has to be given.?

Comment: HEADS UP: Cordova.plist has been replaced with config.xml in recent versions of PhoneGap

Answer (score 32):

In PhoneGap 3.0, you need to edit config.xml in Project folder (note: not the www/config.xml)

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Project folder is correct, but this folder is named www if you create an app with the command line interface (which of course you don't have to do).

Answer (score 18):

In PhoneGap 3.0, you need to edit `www/config.xml`, and add/edit `<access>` tags. For example, if you want to allow everything, change the tag to:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add this following code in Cordova.plist file:

```
<key>ExternalHosts</key>
       <array>
               <string>*.facebook.com</string>
       </array>
```

With `*.facebook.com` as the domain name, you can use two different sub-domains.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to Domain Whitelist so you can access outside domains such as http://google.com.

In iOS (Cordova > 3.0.0), the whitelisting rules are found in `AppName/config.xml` and declared with the element `<access origin="..." />`

You can also use wildcards to declare domains. For example, to allow access to all subdomains and TLDs (.com, .net, etc) of Google, use `*.google.*`

Reference: [Domain Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide)

Comment: The documentation is not quite up to date at the moment. The answers by shawkinaw and Ivan are correct.

Comment: Thanks Deena, followed your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same issue... I fixed it in the below way..In cordova.plist--> under ExternalHosts array menu, add an item as * or *.*. So it allows all the external links... if u have to mention one by one mention it as *.facebook.*,*.google.* etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because phonegap won't take external urls .For phonegap older versions below `2.x` we need to set url in `cordova.plist` like this.

ex:`*.google.co.in`(u can put your url after *. this) and `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView`---to ---`YES`.