# phonegap app ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://xyz.com'

Tags: json, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jsonp

Below is my JSON code

```
$.getJSON("http://xyz.com",function(result){
    alert(result);
]});
```

I get this error whitelist rejection: url='http://xyz.com' ON IPHONE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In cordova/phonegap all external URLs are blocked by default. To change this, you have to add the url in question to the whitelist exception in `Cordova.plist` (XCode).

[image: whitelist exception for one URL]

Alternatively, you could add a `*` wildcard to allow all domains as shown below.

[image: whitelist exception for all external urls]

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your help. Your comments really helped me in solving the problem.

Comment: You're Welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Cordova.plist not available in my project

Comment: @AdarshVC: check config.xml

Answer (score 1):

cordova.2.9/phonegap after have accept all external URLs are by default.

Answer (score 0):

For phonegap 2+ upwards the external hosts are added in the config.xml file:  or replace * with the url like google.com see the second solution here: [Error: Whitelist rejection in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795628/error-whitelist-rejection-in-phonegap?rq=1)