# href not working, how to redirect to a specific page in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

In Html5 I go to a specific page in the following manner:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:XXXX/MyPageName.html";
```

The href by clicking on the button does **not work**!! I have no idea why, it's the only way I could solve this problem.

When I run the html5 application using the PhoneGap, the links do not work (obviously, since there is no localhost to application)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will solve your problems using something like this:

```
<script>
    //action go to pageOther
    $.mobile.changePage('#pageOther','slide');
</script>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageHome">
        //Your html
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="pageOther">
        //Your html
    </div>
</body>
```

See more info: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Answer (score 2):

First, your links might not work, because cordova/phonegap blocks all *external* URLs by default. To fix this, read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682228/phonegap-app-error-whitelist-rejection-url-http-xyz-com/13682715#13682715).

Second, Phonegap does not open a webserver, so `http://localhost` is not correct. When you want to have an internal link, use something like `<a href="/mydir/mypage.html">linkText</a>`.

Comment: Links on the page are not external, just the href does not work (no idea why) so I linked the pages this way.

Comment: I understand. As I said, you can use internal links but need to leave out the `localhost:XXXX`. Use relative links instead, see my example. If I misunderstood your problem, please explain again and I will try my best to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap suggest not having multiple pages. You should have "content" section in one page and then through the dynamic linking (using #page1 where page1 is the content area id)

Example.

all in same html page (index.html)

```
<div data-role="page" id="page0">
<a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="#page1">Page 1</a>
<div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<div>
```

Comment: "Phonegap suggest not having multiple pages." -- This doesn't sound right to me. Can you reference that?

Comment: I meant JQM and referred to multple .html pages. Sorry but cant find the doc where i read it.

Comment: It's still not true -- actually it is quite the oppsote. It is generally recommended to use a single-page layout, which does NOT mean putting all pages into one file, but putting each page into a *separate* file. (Reference: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-template.html)

Comment: So? First off, this is 1.0b2 (out-dated), secondly I can't read any "recommendation" on there. My link clearly states "We strongly recommend building your site or app as a series of separate pages like this because it's cleaner, more lightweight and works better without JavaScript."