# IOS - html links not working - phone gap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, href

I have a pretty standard html file.

What is weird is that the app works on android, the html files work in browser in safari and on windows etc. Everything is fine. However when I go into iOS emulator, literally none of the links work. The purpose of the links are simply to navigate from page to page. I have no idea why they wouldn't work.

Can anyone work this out? I'm also not seeing any console errors.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fonts.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.sidr.dark.css" type="text/css">


</head>

<body class="sign-in">

<!-- PAGE -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="page">

        <div class="container">

            <h1 class="big-logo"></h1>


            <!-- Sign in Form -->
            <section class="sign-in-form">

                <form id="login-form">

                    <div class="input-wrap">
                        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Email Address">
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

                    </div>

                    <a class="btn btn-green" onclick="$('#login-form').submit();"> Sign In </a>

                </form>

            </section>

            <!-- Create Account -->
            <div class="first-time"> First time user? <a href="registration.html"> Create Account </a></div>
            <div class="forgot-password">
                <a href="forgot-password.html"> Forgot your password? </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--// PAGE -->

    </div>
</div>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sidr.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll-probe.js"></script>
<script src="js/touch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

config.xml as requested:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    id="com.gladwinput.testApp"
    version="0.0.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" >

    <name>
Test
    </name>

    <description>
    </description>

    <author
        email="apps@gladwinput.com"
        href="http://gladwinput.com" >
        David G
    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <access origin="*" />

</widget>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13683992/2446155

Comment: Can you post your forgot-password.html (or registration.html) and config.xml? Also, is there any message in the console when you click on the links?

Comment: I don't believe this relates to absolute paths (I use relatives only, and images etc appear, it is just linking that does not).
No messages appear in console when the links are clicked.
I will post the config.xml

Comment: It's possible that one of the classes that you've used has an absolute position or z-index that causes the form to render behind one of wrapper div layers. It's hard to tell what the issue is without all of the CSS. Try getting rid of all of the extraneous wrapper divs and classes to see if that helps.

Comment: Keep it simple, delete everything and see if 1 link works by itself. If it does keep adding more code until you find the problem. I suspect it is what Brian Shamblen is talking about.

Comment: check your path, correct that it should solve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually turned out to be an iScroll bug - it's buggy in the latest version and constantly listens for an ontouch, which meant it was overriding any links. Sorry about that folks!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, i think you have moved your file's[.html] to an group folder or someWhere else.

you need to place the .html files in "WWW" folder only, if you move your files to some other folder means then it will not work.

cut your forgot-password.html & registration.html files and paste them in the WWW directory it will work as coded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the absolute url of your files.. for example

```
<a href="/forgot-password.html"> Forgot your password? </a>
```

Notice the "/".

You need to put the file into www or any folder into www folder.. for example

www/user/forgot-password.html

The link will be:

```
<a href="/user/forgot-password.html"> Forgot your password? </a>
```