# Whitelist rejection in phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I have received error whitelist rejection on my Xcode log. I try to search on the Internet, I found the solution add ExternalHosts key string still dont work for me i dont  know why still got wrong or my value string not correct.i have try these way:

1) * - access all the domain

2) *.abc.com - access all the sub domain

3) abc.com - access only this domain

my ajax request url is like "http://mobile.abc.com".
Hope someone could help me thank you

Comment: The strings are right, may be issue is with the steps you are following. Please explain what are the steps you are following?

Comment: Got any step to follow?I just normally add the ExternalHost and build but fail.

Answer (score 0):

This had me beat too. For phonegap 2+ upwards the external hosts are added in the config.xml file: 
`<access origin="*" />` or replace * with the url like google.com
see the second solution here: [Error: Whitelist rejection in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795628/error-whitelist-rejection-in-phonegap?rq=1)