# sencha touch debug emulator failures

Tags: android-emulator, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch example application which works fine on browser (using `sencha web start`) and iOS and Android simulators (built with `phonegap` and launched using `sencha app build -run native`).
I made few changes and was testing in browser alone, unfortunately. When I finally launched the app in simulators, app does not launch. I do not see the main view corresponding screen. It shows a blank screen on app launch. Application works fine in simulator browser as well. App based launch alone fails.

How do I troubleshoot the app failures on simulator? Are there any logs I need to look at? Have no clue.
I have `Sencha Touch 2.3.1`  and `Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84` on ubuntu OS. 
No IDE as of now.

**UPDATE**
Was able to narrow it down to the store problem. I am trying to launch the [First App](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/first_app) in sencha docs. Store is making ajax call to [googleapis](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog). Not sure if this is causing the problem. I changed this to use local store and app launch worked fine. No idea why app is not able to get the data from googleapis. Simulator browser is able to get the data but just not the app.

Comment: what does logcats says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the update, app tried to access google api url to get the json data. config.xml in project's root folder prevented access to external domains. As a result app failed to render the view. Fixing it as mentioned in [Error: Whitelist rejection in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795628/error-whitelist-rejection-in-phonegap) to allow required domains worked.

```
   <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    -->
   <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
```

Change <access origin= to <access origin="*"/> to allow all domains or use your specific domains.